# Different detail level in actuator health

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Can I have different details in the Actuator Health response depending on the request?
If this is the response from http://localhost:8080/actuator/health

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "components": {
    "db": {
        ...
      }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
        ...
      }
    },
    "ping": {
      ...
    },
    "my-custom-component": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "detail-a": "a"       
        "detail-b": "b" <-- Can I keep this out of here?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

can I have a different response from http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/my-custom-component?

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "details": {
    "detail-a": "a"       
    "detail-b": "b" <-- But keep it here?
  }
}
```

The Health method is very simple at the moment:

```
@Override
public Health health() {
    Health.Builder  status = Health.up();
    return status
            .withDetail("detail-a", "a")
            .withDetail("detail-b", "b")
            .build();
}
```

The main point is that I want to keep the top level health indicator less detailed.

Comment: will this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/62783669/2987755

Comment: @dkb, It was helpful, but eventually I opted for an org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation